# Index Out of Range for Large List Unless Last Element is Deleted

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am facing a problem where I have a fairly large nested list (56k nested lists) created from a csv file. Each nested list contains 4 strings. I am trying to find nested lists which contains a specific string at a particular location.

I keep getting an IndexError although I noticed the error disappears if I deleted the last nested list.

Can someone explain why?

Code below and attached jpg to illustrate

Thank you for any help.

```
import csv

with open('c:\\users\\user\\desktop\\MeshTreeHierarchy.csv', 'rb') as f:

    reader = csv.reader((x.replace('\0', '') for x in f), delimiter='\t')
    # the line above addresses problem of null bytes in the csv file

    main_list = list(reader)

#    IndexError is not thrown if the del line below is made active
#    del main_list[-1:]

    chosen_list = [x for x in main_list if 'Hallux' in x[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that your last line is different, and therefore can not  be properly parsed?

Comment: When you're debugging an issue like this, many programmers will add a "print" statement just before the line that raises the error, so they can see for themselves why it's failing (note: advanced programmers will use a debugger). Consider using `print` more often, because now SO users have to guess at the error, because you didn't upload the file.

Comment: @OliverW. Yes I should do that. That's very helpful. Thanks. I did try to run through the 56k nested lists and it seemed ok but it's probably more thorough to incorporate a print statement to isolate when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is probably thrown because the last element in your List has less than three entries.

In that case `[x for x in main_list if 'Hallux' in x[2]]` will fail, since `x[2]`
does not exist.

You can try a workaround like this:

```
[x for x in main_list if 'Hallux' in (x[2] if len(x)>2 else [])]
```

But deleting the last row is also correct, since it seems that it doesn't belong to the rest of the data

Comment: Thanks. Strangely though it seems that the last element is not the only one without an empty index 2. Maybe it's because intervening nested lists with empty index 2 still has an empty string in it while the last one doesn't?

Comment: Probably, your code should not have problems with something like `["a","b","","c"]`.
As long as the `length` of each nested list is longer than 3 it works and afaik csv reader fills up your list with empty strings if you have an empty value followed by others.

Comment: So reading `a,b,,c` gives an array of length 4, because there is an empty value. But reading `a,b` only gives a length of 2 regardless of how long previous lines were.